# Calling various function based on input in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, function, call

I'm writing some code to get various data from a class (which extracts data from a '.csv' file). I was wondering if there was a way to call one of these methods based off the name of an input

I've attempted to create a function called get(), which takes in 'param_name' - the name of the method contained within the class that I want to call. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to solve this without creating a large amount of if statements.

```
def get(param_name):
    # Some initialisation of the .csv file goes here. This works as intended.

    list_of_objects = [] # Initialised above, as a list of objects with methods function1(), function2() for getting data out of the .csv
    for item in list_of_objects:
        if param_name == "name of function 1":
            return function1()
        if param_name == "name of function 2":
            return function2()
```

Comment: Why make a `for` loop if you're always going to `return` at the first iteration? And why is `item` not used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your functions ina a dictionary as such:

```
function_dict = {
    'function_1': function_1, 
    'function_2': function_2
}
```

To use these you could do:

```
function_to_use = function_dict.get(param_name)
function_to_use(*args, **kwargs) # *args, **kwargs are arguments to be used.
```

If you want to return a list after you have applied the function to all `item` in `list_of_objects` instead of the for loop you could do:

```
list(map(function_to_use, list_of_objects))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Could you mark it as resolved then please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `__getattribute__`:

```
class Alpha:
    def f1(self):
        print("F1")

x = Alpha()
x.__getattribute__('f1')()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `globals()`, globals() returns a dict containing all methods and attributes.

```
def fun1():
    print('this is fun1')

def fun2():
    print('this is fun2')

def get(func_name):
    globals()[func_name]()

get('fun1')
get('fun2')
```

Will Output:

```
this is fun1
this is fun2
```